# Convert odt to html

Tags: html, текст

Задание очень простое, но не могу найти инструмент. Нужно конвертировать **ODT** ещё лучше **FODT** (но тут вообще ничего не нашёл) в **HTML**

Применение: для epub

Форматирования практически нет никакого:

- Заголовки
- Курсив
- Жирный
- Текст с отступом

Ни таблиц, ничего подобного

Было испробовано

1. **Онлайнконвертеры.** Пихают много чего не нужного. Почти каждое слово обвертывают в `<span>`
2. **abiword** все бы ничего, но добавляет ненужные аттрибуты в теги `<p class="" style="text-align:justify" awml:style="Normal">`
3. **pandoc** к заголовкам добавляет id `<h3 id="затмение">Затмение</h3>` Вследствие документ не проходит валидацию (параметры кириллицей), кстати **abiword** делает то же самое.

Неужели вручную потом править?

Мысль уже была написать простенький скрипт. НО? Неужели нет ничего готового. Задача-то
вполне обычная и распространенная.

Comment: Пробовали [Calibre](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#convert-odt-documents)?

Comment: @Spatz, не понравилось. Пользуюсь Sigil, но там нужно готовый HTML добавлять